# Camel-Quartz2 : Running multiple instance in AWS Cluster and causing duplicates

Tags: apache-camel, quartz

I have a camel quartz2 enabled service coded via spring DSL . The service is deployed in an AWS Cluster which has 3 instances running. The quartz2 service deployed in all 3 instances and all 3 start at the same time which is meant to be. The three services make an outbound service call simultaneously  to an external system thus causing duplicates at the end system.

To avoid this we have manually stopped the bundles in 2 instances and just made the service bundle to run only from one instance.

Is there anyway I can configured quartz2 via spring DSL , to make sure that quartz starts from just one instance and the rest automatically understand there is a process in-progress and don't start.

My current configuration is :

```
<from uri="quartz2://getClaim/getClaimTrigger?cron={{pollCronEntry}}" />
```

Comment: You could have a look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26066662/5891534

Comment: There is also the master component in Camel. But you need something to coordinate in the AWS cluster for leader election. The master component can plugin to different implementations.

Comment: I have now configured the consumer endpoint to look like: <from uri="master:"NAME-SPACE":quartz2://getClaim/getClaimTrigger?cron={{pollCronEntry" />}}....... I'm not sure if this is correct and what would the namespace value be?