# Record processing by multiple instance application by zookeeper

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, apache-zookeeper

I have a micro-service application which has scheduler to pick data from DB based on `isProcessed=false` flag . It runs continuously every 1 second and polls 50 records at a time. On successful read and after processing it updates value of rows to `isProcessed=true` . I am using JDBC select and update to perform DB operation on application .

Currently I am running a single instance of application and if I want to run multiple instances of micro-service it will be race condition in rows of DB . Multiple instances of application polls same  rows and update twice . How to avoid multiple poll of same record in multi instance application .

Is there any way to use [zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) to coordinate between multiple instance to have information of picked DB records . In multi instance DB rows read by one instance should be locked and should not be read by other .

My table looks like ( 1,2,3 is unprocessed and 4,5 is processed and updated)

```
---------------------------
C1 | C2 | C3 | isProcessed
----------------------------
1  | a  | 3  | false
2  | b  | 3  | false
3  | c  | 3  | false
4  | d  | 3  | true
5  | f  | 3  | true
```

Running multiple instances will improve my record DB processing performance as multiple instance will work on same DB . How to avoid overlapping/ processing same record via different micro-service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why ZooKeeper? ZooKeeper is used to coordinate multiple processes on different nodes. Why not to use some flag in the DB table so that the work is distributed among different micro-services? Micro-service 1 processes records with flag 1, Micro-service 2 processes records with flag 2, and so on, and the flag is generated randomly according to number of active micro-services. You might also use different tables for each client or different partitions of the same table. You might also use a sequence for the flag on the table and store the value of the flag that each micro-service is currently processing (flag-flag + 49) on a different table where each client has its own entry. Row locking might be useful as well.

Comment: My rows in table is always increasing and not fixed . Other service is keep on inserting record in table . Partitioning table by fixed range might be challenging as new rows keep getting added . Could you please explain the idea of having multiple flag is table .

Comment: If i understand if 3 instances are running flag1,flag2 and flag3 columns will be available .  On select I do not update which instance had picked particular row . There could be chances that two different instance picks same row as none of flag column in updated on select . On successful process rows gets updated .

Comment: The idea of using zookeeper i got from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066012/clustering-in-apache-camel-multiple-jvms-same-camelcontext

Comment: Why 3 columns? One column with values 1, 2, 3 or any identifier of the client to be used for processing. You randomly insert the values 1, 2, 3 on the column so your 3 clients simply process one third of the records. Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of having different column for different instances , I can run multiple instances with select statement doing mod operation of row number

Comment: Yes, each client uses a different value for the flag column selecting the 50 records.

Comment: In case of increase or decrease of instances flag columns need to increased or decreased . I was looking for any clean solution in which central point knows which instance has requested how much record and its currently under processing . If zookeeper can keep record that which instances has read how much and currently under-processing . If it can help to know which all rows are given to which all instance , so not to select already under processing rows .

Comment: If you increase the number of processors from 3 to 4 you only need to modify the process that populates the flag column to generate random numbers in the interval 1,2,3,4 instead of 1,2,3. If you don't do that the fourth processor simply does not process anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240548/discussion-between-sumeet-kumar-yadav-and-saxon).

Comment: That's what I meant.